# Next props returns undefined React + Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

All i did here was to create a component that has a button to change the state in the store so i created mapDispatchToProps which dispatched the action in the button `onClick` event handler

```
export class ProductCard extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <div className="ImageCard" style={{backgroundImage:"url("+this.props.image+")"}}>
        <div className= "product-details">{this.props.details}</div>
        <button
          className="TheButton btn btn-dark"
          onClick = {(e)=>{
            console.log(this.props);
            this.props.updateData(1)}}>Click Here</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  updateData: (data) => dispatch(changeState(data))
});

componentWillReceiveProps ({data}) {
  console.log("next props",data)
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  data:state.data,
  title:state.title
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(ProductCard);
```

this is the code for the store

```
const initstate={
  data:0,
  title:'rr'
}
const store = createStore((state=initstate , action)=>{
  if (typeof state === 'undefined') {
    console.log("lo");
    return 0;
  }
  switch(action.type){
    case types.CHANGESTATE:{
      console.log(state)
      return state.data + action.data;
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
});
```

When i log the next props i get the `data` and `title` undefined, could you tell me what i'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your reducer, you **ALWAYS** have to return a new object that will represent your new state. In your `CHANGESTATE` action, you are not returning an object, you are only returning a number (`state.data + action.data`). Try returning this object:

```
{ ...state, data: state.data + action.data }
```

So your full `case` would look like:

```
case types.CHANGESTATE: {
  console.log(state)
  return {
    ...state,
    data: state.data + action.data
  };
}
```